# Flutter pixel coordinates to offset

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

So I have a third-party library in my Flutter app which sends me messages.
A message can for example be represented in the following json format

```
{
  objects: [
    {
      'name': 'Name of obj1',
      'x1': 107,
      'y1': 1012,
      'x2': 117,
      'y2': 974
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The `x` and `y` propertiess are screen coordinates (express in pixels).
Suppose now that I want to draw a Text (with the name property of an object in the message) that animates from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)` based on the data from the messages.

I looked at [AnimatedPositioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html) which refered me to [SlideTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html)

> If the size is intended to remain the same, with only the position changing over time, then consider SlideTransition instead. SlideTransition only triggers a repaint each frame of the animation, whereas AnimatedPositioned will trigger a relayout as well.

Now the example provided in the flutter doc of [SlideTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html) works with Offset going from `Offset.zero` to `Offset(1.5, 0.0)`. But what exactly are these units expressed in? And how can I provide my screen coordinates to the Flutter Offset units?

I deliberatly gave a bit of the background to note that I cannot change anything about the format that these messages come in. I simply need to convert the screen coordinates to an offset, relative to the root of the application, not to its parent ofcourse.

Comment: If this value is in pixels how do you manage small devices or tablets? X axis 500 pixels will be out of screen for small devices and not even half way through in tablet. Do you have a reference pixel value also in the list that you recieve?

Comment: @KaushikChandru the pixels that are being sent to me are correct. The third party library is embedded in the Flutter app and has access to the screen size/dimension. Flutter has this too using `window.physicalSize`

Comment: @pskink the documentation explicitely told me to consider the `SlideTransition`. I also in my app need FULL control over my widgets. The `AnimatedPositioned` resulted in strange behaviour especially when the messages come in while the animation is still busy. In such a case I need to animate from the current position to the newest and not the one set at an earlier stage.

Comment: with `SlideTransition` it would be hard to do what you want, from what i saw you want to position your labels anywhere (i mean they could stay in any place of the screen: appbar, main content area, bottom navigational bar) - is that true?

Comment: That is mostly correct. i want to display them somewhere on the screen using the pixels sent to me. But the pixels being sent are definitely correct and won't interfere with a possible appbar. What I want to do is actually not that big of a deal. I only need to know how to translate raw pixels to a Flutter Offset. But the documentation refuses to give anything usefull to me. It does not express anything about the units or relativeness

Comment: basically you need an `Overlay` - it occupies the whole screen so there is no need to translate your raw pixel data - you can just use it as it is since `Overlay`'s top-left corner is screen's top-left corner (however if you **really** want global-local mapping you can use `RenderBox.globalToLocal` and `localToGlobal` methods - i dont recommend it though... - the solution with `Overlay` is imho better)

Answer (score 0):

```
double leftPosition = data[0]['x1'];
double topPosition = data[0]['y1'];
```

Call a future.delayed setting left and top position to the next value like

```
    Future.delayed(duration: Duration (seconds:1), (){
  leftPosition = data[0]['x2'];
  topPosition = data[0]['y2'];
 setState((){});

});
```

Then

```
 Stack(
  children:[
  AnimatedPositioned(
  duration : Duration(seconds : 1),
  left : leftPosition,
  top: topPosition,
 )
 ]
),
```

This should take values in pixels. Please excuse if there are any mistakes. Wrote it from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

if you "need FULL control over my widgets" i would recommend [CustomMultiChildLayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) which not only lets you know your child widgets size during the layout phase (so you can align them within some `Offset`) but also supports "animated" layout *without* rebuilding the children - in "normal" `Stack` widget you would need to wrap it with `LayoutBuilder` (to get the whole layout size) and `AnimatedBuilder` (for motion animation) and also you would need to rebuild your children on every animation frame

here you have two versions: the first one uses `Overlay` and has a very simple logic of child positioning, the second one uses `RenderBox` and the child positioning is more complex

the version that uses `Overlay`:

```
class AnimatedLabels extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AnimatedLabels> createState() => _AnimatedLabelsState();
}

class _AnimatedLabelsState extends State<AnimatedLabels> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late OverlayEntry entry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );
    entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (ctx) {
        final colors = [
          Colors.orange, Colors.green, Colors.lime,
        ];
        final data = [
          {'name': 'orange label', 'x1': 150.0, 'y1': 400.0, 'x2': 50.0, 'y2': 100.0},
          {'name': 'green label',  'x1': 10.0,  'y1': 56.0,  'x2': 65.0, 'y2': 125.0},
          {'name': 'lime label',   'x1': 200.0, 'y1': 56.0,  'x2': 80.0, 'y2': 150.0},
        ];
        return CustomMultiChildLayout(
          delegate: LabelDelegate(controller, data),
          children: List.generate(3, (i) => LayoutId(
            id: i,
            child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
              elevation: 3,
              color: colors[i],
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(data[i]['name'] as String),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        );
      },
    );
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(insertOverlay);
  }

  insertOverlay(Duration d) {
    print('insertOverlay $entry');
    Overlay.of(context)!.insert(entry);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('press me to start animation'),
        onPressed: () => controller.value < 0.5? controller.forward() : controller.reverse()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LabelDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final AnimationController controller;
  final List<Map> offsets;

  LabelDelegate(this.controller, List<Map> data) :
    offsets = [for (final d in data) {
      'from': Offset(d['x1'] as double, d['y1'] as double),
      'to': Offset(d['x2'] as double, d['y2'] as double),
    }],
    super(relayout: controller);

  @override
  void performLayout(ui.Size size) {
    final looseBoxConstraints = BoxConstraints.loose(size);
    // final curve = controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward? Curves.elasticOut : Curves.elasticIn;
    final curve = controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward? Curves.easeOutBack : Curves.easeInBack;
    final t = curve.transform(controller.value);

    int id = 0;
    for (final offsetMap in offsets) {
      // print('$id: $offsetMap');
      final size = layoutChild(id, looseBoxConstraints);

      // the most important line of this code:
      positionChild(id, Offset.lerp(offsetMap['from'], offsetMap['to'], t)!);
      id++;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

the version that uses `RenderBox`:

```
class AnimatedLabels2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AnimatedLabels2> createState() => _AnimatedLabels2State();
}

class _AnimatedLabels2State extends State<AnimatedLabels2> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  final key = GlobalKey();
  final globalOffset = ValueNotifier<Offset?>(null);

  final colors = [
    Colors.orange, Colors.green, Colors.lime,
  ];
  final data = [
    {'name': 'orange label', 'x1': 150.0, 'y1': 400.0, 'x2': 50.0, 'y2': 100.0},
    {'name': 'green label',  'x1': 10.0,  'y1': 56.0,  'x2': 65.0, 'y2': 125.0},
    {'name': 'lime label',   'x1': 200.0, 'y1': 56.0,  'x2': 80.0, 'y2': 150.0},
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
    );
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(setGlobalOffset);
  }

  setGlobalOffset(Duration d) {
    final renderBox = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    globalOffset.value = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print('globalOffset: ${globalOffset.value}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Stack(
      key: key,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('press me to start animation'),
            onPressed: () => controller.value < 0.5? controller.forward() : controller.reverse()
          ),
        ),
        CustomMultiChildLayout(
          delegate: LabelDelegate2(controller, data, globalOffset),
          children: List.generate(3, (i) => LayoutId(
            id: i,
            child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
              elevation: 3,
              color: colors[i],
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(data[i]['name'] as String),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class LabelDelegate2 extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final AnimationController controller;
  final List<Map> offsets;
  final ValueNotifier<Offset?> globalOffset;

  LabelDelegate2(this.controller, List<Map> data, this.globalOffset) :
    offsets = [for (final d in data) {
      'from': Offset(d['x1'] as double, d['y1'] as double),
      'to': Offset(d['x2'] as double, d['y2'] as double),
    }],
    super(relayout: Listenable.merge([controller, globalOffset]));

  @override
  void performLayout(ui.Size size) {
    // print(globalOffset);

    final looseBoxConstraints = BoxConstraints.loose(size);
    // final curve = controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward? Curves.elasticOut : Curves.elasticIn;
    final curve = controller.status == AnimationStatus.forward? Curves.easeOutBack : Curves.easeInBack;
    final t = curve.transform(controller.value);

    int id = 0;
    for (final offsetMap in offsets) {
      // print('$id: $offsetMap');
      final size = layoutChild(id, looseBoxConstraints);

      // the most important line of this code:
      positionChild(id, Offset.lerp(offsetMap['from'], offsetMap['to'], t)! - (globalOffset.value ?? Offset.zero));
      id++;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

**EDIT** added a modified version of `RenderBox` solution showing how to implement the case when the change of location happens when the animation is still running: note that not only the whole animation is continuous but also the animated object  behaves as if it was a real object with some mass (so it does not change the final direction at once) - it was done by simple use of `SpringSimulation`

```
class AnimatedLabels3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<AnimatedLabels3> createState() => _AnimatedLabels3State();
}

class _AnimatedLabels3State extends State<AnimatedLabels3> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controllerX, controllerY;
  late LabelDelegate3 delegate;
  final key = GlobalKey();
  final globalOffset = ValueNotifier<Offset?>(null);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controllerX = AnimationController.unbounded(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    );
    controllerY = AnimationController.unbounded(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    );
    delegate = LabelDelegate3(controllerX, controllerY, globalOffset);
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(setGlobalOffset);
  }

  setGlobalOffset(Duration d) {
    final renderBox = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    globalOffset.value = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print('globalOffset: ${globalOffset.value}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Stack(
      children: [
        const Center(child: Text('tap anywhere to start animation\n\nalso try to tup again while animation is still in progress')),
        GestureDetector(
          onPanDown: (d) {
            delegate.simulateNewTargetPosition(d.globalPosition);
          },
        ),
        CustomSingleChildLayout(
          key: key,
          delegate: delegate,
          child: SizedBox.square(
            dimension: 64,
            child: Container(
              width: 64,
              height: 64,
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                shadows: [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 4, spreadRadius: 1, offset: Offset(3, 3))],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

final springDescription = SpringDescription.withDampingRatio(mass: 8, stiffness: 100);

class LabelDelegate3 extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  final AnimationController controllerX;
  final AnimationController controllerY;
  final ValueNotifier<Offset?> globalOffset;
  Offset current = Offset.zero;
  Simulation
    sx = SpringSimulation(springDescription, 0, 0, 0),
    sy = SpringSimulation(springDescription, 0, 0, 0);

  LabelDelegate3(this.controllerX, this.controllerY, this.globalOffset) :
    super(relayout: Listenable.merge([controllerX, controllerX, globalOffset]));

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    current = Offset(controllerX.value, controllerY.value);
    // the most important line of this code:
    return current - (globalOffset.value ?? Offset.zero) - childSize.center(Offset.zero);
  }

  void simulateNewTargetPosition(ui.Offset position) {
    // timeDilation = 5;
    sx = SpringSimulation(springDescription, current.dx, position.dx, 2 * controllerX.velocity);
    sy = SpringSimulation(springDescription, current.dy, position.dy, 2 * controllerY.velocity);
    controllerX.animateWith(sx);
    controllerY.animateWith(sy);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant SingleChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```